# Can we turn off MouseEvents?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, flashdevelop

I've been doing some testing regarding the MouseEvents. Thanks to Neal Davis, most of it was clarified for me. Now, I want to design codes such that whenever I left click, it will begin to draw circles along the mouse's x and y coordinates. When I let go of the left mouse click, it will stop drawing circles. I tried to replicate this as much as possible but this is where I eventually got stuck:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mClickOn);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMove);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mClickOff);

public var clickOn:Boolean;
public var clickOff:Boolean;

public function mClickOn(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    clickOn = e.buttonDown;
}

public function mClickOff(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    clickOff = e.buttonDown
}

public function mMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (clickOn) //keep drawing when left click
    {
        draw.create(e.localX, e.localY);
        addChild(draw);
    }
    else if (clickOff) //don't draw when you let go of left click
    {
        null;
    }
}
```

The problem was that MOUSE_DOWN is true when left clicked but I assumed that when we're not left clicking anymore, it'll automatically return back to false. To my testing, it stays true after the first click. As for CLICK, it's always false.

How do I make it such that these MouseEvents can be turned on and off? I want to make a pencil tool/simulator.

Comment: Please make sure to check out the API reference material I posted on your last question. There really is a lot of good stuff in there that it looks like you haven't read.

Comment: Your else if/null block is pointless. All if blocks have that implied. If X then do y *if not do nothing*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the idea:

1. When the mouse button goes down, set a flag to true, and set it to false when the mouse goes up.
2. Check the value of that flag every application loop (either a timer event or enter frame event)
3. Begin listening for the MOUSE_DOWN when the "draw circles" tool is selected.
4. Stop listening for MOUSE_DOWN when the mouse is down and begin listening for MOUSE_UP
5. When the mouse goes up, begin listening for MOUSE_DOWN again and stop listening for MOUSE_UP.
6. then stop listening for MOUSE_DOWN when the tool is in selected. (I don't show the tool election and deselection part below. Hopefully you get the idea though. For each tool, you'll need to replicate this process)

Do something like this:

```
private function mDown(me:MouseEvent):void{
    _mDown = true;
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);
}

private function mUp(me:MouseEvent):void{
    _mDown = false;
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mDown);
}
```

and then you'll need a appTick or gameLoop or timerEvent such as

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, applicationLoop);

private function applicationLoop(e:Event):void{
    if (_mDown == true){
        drawCircles();
    }
```

and then

```
private function drawCircles():void{
    // your draw logic
}
```

That should do it.

**NOTE**
if you want to draw circles the way a spray paint tool works (keeps adding more paint even when the mouse isn't moving) check the `_mDown` flag each frame. If you want it to only add circles when the mouse is moving then check the flag on a MOUSE_MOVE event instead.

Comment: Awesome! This worked out perfectly. Thanks again Neal Davis!

Comment: You bet. Glad it worked for you. Make sure to check out those API documents ;)

Answer (score 0):

A click is pressing the mouse button down and letting go again. This is not useful for your situation as you want to look at the down and up of the mouse individually, to start or stop the drawing process. Using `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` is more appropriate here.

To start and stop the process, simply add or remove the listener to toggle between the two states of drawing and not drawing.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);

public function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove); 
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
}

public function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);  
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
}

public function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    draw.create(e.localX, e.localY);
    addChild(draw);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried out this code too! Added to my notes